Why the lifetime of self differs from a lifetime of trait that was implemented by self?
I have a struct and this struct implements callback trait. This struct also holds a pointer for some trait object. Then i call a method of that struct where i want to pass the reference to the callback trait (that implemented by that struct) into trait object that is held by one. I specified same lifetime for all trait objects and references.
When i try to build the code that compiler says that that lifetime of self less what lifetime of reference to the callback. But originally this is the same reference.
37 | impl <'a>MainStruct<'a> {
   |       -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
46 |     pub fn start(&self) {
   |                  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
47 |         self.some_interface.register_callback(Box::new(self));
   |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`

I'm really confused here could anyone explain me why it happens?
Rust playground
fn main() {
    let some_interface_impl = SomeInterfaceImpl();

    let main_struct = MainStruct {
        some_interface: Box::new(some_interface_impl)
    };

    main_struct.start();
}

pub struct MainStruct<'a> {
    some_interface: Box<dyn SomeInterface<'a> + 'a>,
}

trait SomeInterface<'a> {
    fn register_callback(&self, callback: Box<dyn Callback + 'a>);
}

struct SomeInterfaceImpl();

trait Callback {
    fn one(&self);
    fn two(&self);
}

impl<'a> SomeInterface<'a> for SomeInterfaceImpl {
    fn register_callback(&self, callback: Box<dyn Callback + 'a>) {}
}

impl<'a> MainStruct<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> MainStruct<'a> {
        let trait_object = SomeInterfaceImpl {};

        Self {
            some_interface: Box::new(trait_object),
        }
    }

    pub fn start(&self) {
        self.some_interface.register_callback(Box::new(self));
    }
}

impl<'a> Callback for &'a MainStruct<'a> {
    fn one(&self) {
        println!("One");
    }

    fn two(&self) {
        println!("Two");
    }
}


What you're putting into the box is an &MainStruct, and the signature of register_callback requires that to have the 'a lifetime, hence the error.  Fundamentally the problem here is that you want MainStruct to be self-referential (ie its some_interface field will reference the MainStruct itself), which is difficult to do in Rust because It requires the MainStruct first be pinned to prevent it from being moved and invalidating the reference.
